# What's the most pythonic way of importing types for testing - and why?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-typing

Let's imagine a setup like

```py
class Implementation:
    def method() -> ...
        ...


class FakeImplementation(Implementation):
    # Overrides whatever methods are required for the test
    def method() -> ...
        ...
```

The implementation has no abstract class for historical reasons. (*Bonus question: is it even strictly necessary to create an abstract interface in Python, compared to just overriding methods with the same signature?*)

The real question comes here:

I can choose to import either the real implementation's type, or a derived fake's type. Both follow the same interface, so they're equally valid.

Consider

```py
module.py:
    from library import Implementation

test_module.py
    from module import Implementation       # 1
    from library import Implementation      # 2
    from testing import FakeImplementation  # 3

    def some_test(implementation: ...): -> ...
        ...                    # 4 ^
```

- Which import style is most "correct"? To me they all seem equivalent, except if the imported object is an enum, in which case `#1` would be preferred to avoid messing up import paths, and have them not be equivalent with `is`.
- What's the best type for the test? Does it matter? One might say the real type should be used, so even statically, the code doesn't know it's being tested, since a `isinstance(FakeImplementation, Implementation) == True`, but on the other hand one might say it slightly obscures the fact that you're using a fake object to "prove" something in a test.

Any authority on this?

Comment: If you are not changing `Implementation` in `module`, there is no reason to import it from `module` and not `library` - it introduces a pointless dependancy.

Comment: You should import things from where they are defined, not from where they are also imported

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "best code for test". Fake implementations, more commonly known as mocks, are most definitely used  in order to simulate parts of the code you are not testing (for example, if you have a app with database you certainly want to test your connection and interfacing with the database - but when it is done, you don't really need to keep pulling data out of the db for other tests, and can mock that behaviour with some other object that will make tests easier to run and or faster.)

Comment: @matszwecja best _type_ for the test, e.g. would you type it `implementation: Implementation` or `implementation: FakeImplementation`?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych are you sure that's true? sometimes it's useful to reexport items higher up the module tree for simpler imports

Comment: "is it even strictly necessary to create an abstract interface in Python, compared to just overriding methods with the same signature?" yes, usually. A class needs to fulfill the contract of its parents, so if your fake implementation doesn't fulfill the contract of your actual implementation, but they have similarities, you probably want a shared interface

Comment: @joel As with everything this is not a strict rule, but I think it's more explicit and simplifies debugging as it's simpler to find the definition of imported things. And as @matszwecja mentioned, this avoids unnecessary dependency, because if you delete the import in your `module`, your test will break due to `ImportError`. In contrast, if you import the class from `library` this won't happen.